# How to access value under a node with firebase functions

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My firebase database does look like this:

- eventDetails

  - EventId

    - title: ""
    - date: ""
- events - attendees

  - EventId

    - userId 1 : true
    - userId 2 : true
    - userId 3 : true

I´m trying to access the userId´s of the attendees using javascript and node.js.
I´m getting the EventId with the following code:

```
exports.observeEvent = functions.database.ref('/eventDetails/{eventId}').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {

  var eventId = context.params.eventId;
  console.log('EventId: ' + eventId);

});
```

How do I access the userId`s?

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a snapshot, so you can use the normal methods of [`DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot) to access it. To loop over the users:

```
exports.observeEvent = functions.database.ref('/eventDetails/{eventId}').onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
  var eventId = context.params.eventId;
  console.log('EventId: ' + eventId);

  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    console.log(child.key+": "+child.val());
  })

});
```